# How to use Firebase documentation? Have trouble upgrading to v9 modular

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to update Firebase to 9.9.1, but it's really frustrating.

First example:

How this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth#authonauthstatechanged
[image]
actually reflects this:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  // Check for user status
});
```

This is example of how documentation is not up to par with the current code.

Now the real problem I have is how to make this v9 modular-compatible:

`const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()`

I tried this:

```
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
  const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
```

but seriously no clue how to handle it. I'm seriously tired of this Firebase thing. To update it from 9.1.3 to 9.9.1 I just constantly get this error:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/idb/build/index.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (83:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| }
| replaceTraps((oldTraps) => ({
|     ...oldTraps,
|     get: (target, prop, receiver) => getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.get(target, prop, receiver),
|     has: (target, prop) => !!getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.has(target, prop),

 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js 5:0-29
 @ ./node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I'm just seriously frustrated bc of how much time it takes and how little documentation over it there is.

edit: the latest working version of Firebase for me is 9.7.0 so something broke at 9.8.0

Comment: `getIdToken(auth.currentUser, true);` - it is actually always the same pattern. instead of concatenating function calls you just nest them as parameters

Comment: What did you based this on? I mean, is there a place in docs I can see more examples bc there are so few of them and some of them are even misleading

Comment: It's not even in a reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth I'm even more frustrated at this point

Comment: Faced the same issue some weeks ago and searched through the type declarations in the firebase v9 module in my project. The auth part of v9 is indeed not that good documented at this point